# Is using a slog-2 and xavcs like profile worth it on the Sony A6000?

Tags: color-grading

I want to make movies, but I currently have a Sony A6000.  I currently use a neutral profile and drop all the values to -3,-3,+3 or -3,-3,-3.  The Sony A6000, however, has only 8bit video.  I also raised the bit rate to maximize the information.  So is it worth it to use a slog-2 like the profile? Also, if the xavcs codec worth using to get more information?

Comment: From experience with S-Log (not on a sony) the trade-off you have for the extra dynamic range is a significant increase in noise in the midtones, particularly if you're shooting to a compressed format. That was with a Panasonic DVX200. As always, do some tests if you can.